# Merging folders in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have two folders in Ubuntu One that came from two diferent notebooks, and one of them crashed. Is there a way to merge those folders using the web interface, so all files will be in the folder of the remaining notebook?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I presume by folders, you mean folders in your home directory, which are not the `~/Ubuntu One/` folder, or within it.

There is no way to "merge" your folders into a single folder on the web site. You can however, simply open the Ubuntu One control panel application on the second notebook, and under the `Folders` tab, select the additional folder to be synchronized to that computer as well. One you do, the client will download that folder and its files, to your notebook.